# Is it possible to include markup with a custom form in wicket?

Tags: java, wicket

I'm trying to implement a form that I can reuse for adding or editing an object. I've noticed if I define a class extending Form that I have to declare the markup for all the form components in the HTML of the page where I'm creating an instance of this form.

I've tried placing a corresponding HTML file with my custom Form class in its package, but it doesn't pick up the fact that the HTML goes with the Java class.

Basically I want the form to look exactly the same, but just to be able to override the onSubmit method of the form so I can use different values when I call setResponsePage for the form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wicket's `Form` doesn't support the same pattern of aligning with corresponding markup that many other wicket component classes do.

When I want to do something like this, I wrap the form in a `Panel` subclass, put the form markup in the corresponding markup for that class, and can then include the panel in multiple pages without having to duplicate the markup.

If you have multiple forms with the same markup, you can also either pass the form itself into the panel as a parameter, or have logic in the panel code that decides which variant to use.

Another possibility for your specific purpose is to pass the response page as a parameter on creating the form and then if that's the only difference you don't need to create two forms.

Comment: +1 This is good advice. The only part maybe I'd change is the last suggestion. It might be easier/lighter to let the panel decide what to do on submit (or how to locate a response page) and let components that use the panel override it.

Comment: @Xavi - Indeed, and if the form is an inner class in the panel, this is quite easy.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to [@DonRoby 's fine comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813312/is-it-possible-to-include-markup-with-a-custom-form-in-wicket/7815597#7815597), you can look at it this way:

- You can only provide Markup for those classes extending `Page`, or `WebMarkupContainerWithAssociatedMarkup`, such as `Panel`, `Border`, `Fragment`.
- The other classes, such as `TextField`, or `Form` just output their markup possibly based on the state of the instance, through their `onComponentTag()`, `onComponentTagBody()`  methods and others. `TextField` outputs `<input ...>`, and `Form` outputs `<form ....> _formbody_ </form>`.

As Don already pointed out, the way to go is to embed this `Form` inside a `Panel`. You can always delegate the `Form.onSubmit()` to a custom method in the wrapping `Panel` and override it as necessary.